# What else do I need to do in order to write to an android device folder?

Tags: android, file, xamarin

Here is my code: using Xamarin in MainActivity.cs
It will say access denied.
I've check write & read external, coarse & find access, and some more accesses.
What else am I missing?

```
var s = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments.ToString(), "test.txt");
```

[image: anything still missing? still need to add permission during run time?]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION in your menifest.xml file.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If your target SDK Version is greater then 23 then you need to Request app permissions on runtime.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java

Comment: Thanks Rehan, now I see it. It happend that I use SDK 23. Now, my next problem is how to use snakebar to ask permission, still a struggle.

Comment: @user2616989 You can use these famous open source libraries to ask run time permissions.
1-https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter
2-https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission
and many more. Please let us know If you need more help.